# Respond to Apology

Tags: responses

If someone apologises for being late, is it pragmatically correct to respond as follow?

> Student: Good morning Mr. Anderson, I’m sorry I’m late!
>
> Teacher: Yes, I can see! So why are you late?

I mean, isn’t it infelicities in English to use “ Yes, I can see!” to mean that the situation is obvious?

Comment: Is this an actual conversation?  Is is from a tv show.  What do you mean by "infelicities"  do you mean "inappropriate"?

Comment: It was made by a non native speaker, therefore, I want to clarify it. Infelicities means it does not meet pragmatics

Comment: If someone apologises for being late, is it **pragmatically correct** to respond as follow? This sentence is rather at odds with itself do you mean is it pragmatic? or do you mean is it correct?

Comment: what does meet pragmatics? Mean.  Pragmatics is the branch of linguistics that analyses how context contributes to meaning.  You seem to be using some technical terms, but I'm not sure you are using them correctly

Comment: The correct spelling is "infelicitous".

Comment: If the student just says "I'm late" then I can understand the teacher saying "I can see that", but if the student says "I'm sorry [that] I'm late" then it seems very odd indeed for the teacher to say "I can see that" - unless it's two separate sentences: "I'm sorry.  I'm late."

Comment: I mean is it authentic, and do native speakers of the English language use such phrase? I want to make sure that the teacher hasn’t translated it directly from his mother tongue( which is to be related to his culture)

Comment: You could ask him what he meant.

Comment: Once I can remember one of my teachers, whose native language is Russian said “ Have you swollen your tongue?” to one of my peers while he remained silent and didn’t answer to her question. And this idiom was directly translated from Russian

Answer (score 2):

The teacher is being sarcastic.

The teacher is mocking the student slightly because the student comes into class and says "I'm late" but doesn't explain why.

It seems an unlikely exchange.  Normally teachers just tell the late student to sit down to avoid disruption, and all good teachers avoid mocking students in front of the class.  But it is not "wrong".  Perhaps the student's tone of voice suggests that the student doesn't understand what is the problem with being late.

Or it may be a simple misspeaking of "Yes, I see."

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

sarcasm
noun [ U ]
UK  /ˈsɑː.kæz.əm/ US  /ˈsɑːr.kæz.əm/

the use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say, made in order to hurt someone's feelings or to criticize something in a humorous way: [Ref CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sarcasm)